# Regular Expression in c# to find letter then \ with capital letter for letter and Shift press form of other charecter?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I want to convert a string like 
`m\anoj ku\mar m\a\noj` 
to 
`Manoj kUmar MAnoj` 
how can i do this using c#

```
string convert(string text)
{
  string pattern = @"$1\\";
  string repPattern =@"";
  string returnText = Regex.Replace(text, repPattern, pattern);
  return returnText;
}
```

What is assigneed to repPattern ? to get result

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: @I4V what about to convert letter to capital?

Answer (score 4):

Try following:

```
var input = @"m\anoj ku\mar m\a\noj";
var pattern = new Regex(@"([a-z])\\");
var replaced = pattern.Replace(input, m => m.Groups[1].ToString().ToUpper());
Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

**UPDATE**

Map digits to shift-pressed form:

```
string text= @"m\an1oj ku\mar m\a\no9j";
char[] shiftPressForms = ")!@#$%^&*(".ToCharArray();
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"([a-z])\\");
Regex pattern_digit = new Regex(@"\d");
string replaced = pattern.Replace(text, m => m.Groups[1].ToString().ToUpper());
replaced = pattern_digit.Replace(replaced, m => shiftPressForms[int.Parse(m.Value)].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

Comment: @falsetru here if i want to convert `9\`` to `(` but this help me so much

Comment: Does m.Value instead of m.Groups[1] suffice?

Comment: @oddparity, If you use `m.Value` you should handle the character `\\`.

Comment: @manoj, Do another replacement: `replaced = replaced.Replace("9", "(");`

Comment: @falsetru acutally 9 is not only a situation i want to convert all charecter of keyboard converted to shift press form i.e. - to _ ,= to + etc

Comment: @manoj, Then make a dictionary (which map digits to shift precess forms) and use that in the replacement callback.

Comment: @manoj - I don't think that there's an easy way to discover the specific keyboard mappings from C# - does the code need to work with *your* keyboard, or with all possible keyboard layouts? `9` doesn't always map to `(` (actually, it may, but other digits such as `2` definitely have different mappings)

Comment: @manoj, I add updated code that will also replace digits with shift-pressed-form. I assumed your keyboard layout is *US*.

Comment: For a more complete solution that replaces with the user's actual keyboard mapping, you'd need calls to native Win32 code - specifically [VkKeyScan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (translates character to key code) and [ToAscii](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[ToUnicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646320(v=vs.85).aspx) (translates key code to character).